# Move cms static block before Breadcrumbs in Magento 2.2 category page

Tags: magento2, cms-block

I want to move cms static block before breadcrumbs. My static block name ves_element_top.

Answer (score 0):

To rearrange elements you need to use the **`<move>`** tag.

Here's the official documentation about it: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange

In your case I reckon the right code would be something that looks like this:

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="your.static.block.name" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Don't forget to change the `element` attribute value with the value of your block name.

Comment: tried but not working